# If-None-Match header always null in asp.net core controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, etag

I send a request with "If-None-Match" header by postman, but it's always `null` in controller.

I'm using Asp.net core 1.1.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

[image]
Debug
[image]
Code

```
if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey("If-None-Match"))
{
    var oldETag = Request.Headers["If-None-Match"].First();
    if (cache.Get($"Tenant-{id}-{oldETag}") != null)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I create a new request with both `If-Match` & `If-None-Match` header, but only `If-Match` header exists in controller `If-None-Match` still `null`.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

"If-None-Match" header is removed by "CSS Hot Reload" feature. You have to disable the hot reload in the Visual Studio options if you want to see the header while debugging.

Comment: Thank you. That's quite absurd, I don't know how much time I would have wasted without this answer

Answer (score 0):

- You look into the wrong header in the debugger. Instead on `HeaderIfMatch` check `HeaderIfNoneMatch`
- `Request.Headers.ContainsKey("If-None-Match")` - this code is fine and works for me via Postman. But, accordingly to screenshot, looks like you add `If-None-Match` as a query parameter, not as a header.

Comment: - HeaderIfNoneMatch is null also. In postman, I added values in header tab, so it is not query string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this syntax?
`request.Headers.Keys.Contains(HeaderNames.IfNoneMatch)`

You can import `HeaderNames` from `using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;`